# postgres : Enforce password change on user first login

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, user-controls, passwords

My script is creating a list of NEW users with DEFAULT password, but I must enfornce them to change their password on their first login PROGRAMMATICALLY.

I do have a command like,

```
CREATE USER david WITH 'PASSWORD'
ALTER USER david VALID UNTIL 'Mar 17 2020';
```

Here I can run above command soon after creating a user, set previous day, but that would expire user TOTAL login itself.
Any other better way/approach ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do this with PostgreSQL.  You can't change the password from outside the database, so once the password is expired you can't get into the database in order to change it (unless you have multiple methods configured, like a certain machine letting you connect without a password). You need to be rescued by a privileged user.

You would need some kind of restricted login which lets you change your password but nothing else, and that does not exist.  (Although it is possible there is some non-core extension that could allow that).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a security definer function that will allow anybody to run it and change their password. But you can't force anybody to change their password. Or - you can include setting up the users' privileges within the same function :)